# How to rotate this arm upwards?

Tags: java, processing

I am learning Java with the program named Processing.
However, I cannot understand why my code do not work appropriately.
I made a arm with this problem which should be rotated to upside or downside when I hold the mouse button, but it just works when I hold the left button on my mouse, and it does not work when I hold the right button.
The problem is I do not know the problem of my code as follows.

```
float angle=0;
float angleDirection=1;
float speed=0.005;

void setup(){
  size(800,600);
}

void draw(){
  background(255,255,255);
  stroke(20,20,255);
  
  translate(400,300);
  rotate(angle);
  strokeWeight(18);
  line(0,0,140,0);
  pushMatrix();
  
  translate(140,0);
  rotate(angle*2.0);
  strokeWeight(14);
  line(0,0,100,0);
  
  translate(100,0);
  rotate(angle*2.5);
  strokeWeight(10);
  line(0,0,60,0);
  
  popMatrix();
  rotate(-angle*2.0);
  strokeWeight(18);
  line(0,0,-140,0);
  
  translate(-140,0);
  rotate(-angle*2.0);
  strokeWeight(14);
  line(0,0,-100,0);
  
  translate(-100,0);
  rotate(-angle*2.5);
  strokeWeight(10);
  line(0,0,-60,0);
  
if(mousePressed){
  if(mouseButton==LEFT){
     angle=angle+speed*angleDirection;
     if((angle>QUARTER_PI)||(angle<0)){
      angle=QUARTER_PI;
      }
      
   if(mouseButton==RIGHT){ 
       angle=angle+speed*angleDirection;
     if((angle>QUARTER_PI)||(angle<0)){
       angleDirection=-angleDirection;
       angle=QUARTER_PI;
       }
      }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is https://processing.org/ releated to Java?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri
[Processing is written in java](https://github.com/processing/processing4/tree/master/core/src/processing/core) and you can use it as a java library. The minimal editor and wealth or utility functions make it easy to sketch/prototype programs in a simpler form. (There are ports of Processing to other languages such as JS (p5.js), Python, etc. but the main/original implementation is in java).

Comment: Hmmm. Java is programmed in C++. Should we not add that label also?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Personally I would c++ and java tags separate otherwise it would be really difficult to manage. A bit of a stretch, but imagine going to a java interview without being a c++ and java programmer and asked to code in c++ because java is programmed in c++. If you're curious you could ask on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). I'm sure there are questions where both c++ and java tags are valid, for example when creating java bindings for c++ libraries (via jni/jna/swig, etc.). My opinion is that in the context of this question the java tag  without the c++ tag should suffice.

Comment: As processing is a language on it's own I believe even the java tag is too much. For the same reason that C++ is too much for java interviews. If on the other hand you insist it should be mentioned because processing is programmed in java, what about the ports you mentioned above?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Again, this is my opinion and you are free to agree or disagree with it. If the OP would've mentioned other languages such as js or python and posted code would have reflected that but the tags were missing I would have suggested adding the tags. Given the default version of Processing is written in java, processing alone could suffice, and it could even help more experienced java devs looking for complex java challenges save time by skipping such a processing question which they may find too trivial. These comments are getting long and I'll stop here.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, but accidentally made a logical error: the right button condition is nested inside the left button condition. Since the `mouseButton` can only be either left or right (but not both), the right button condition will never trigger. Simply move it outside of the left button condition:

```java
if (mousePressed) {
    if (mouseButton==LEFT) {
      angle=angle+speed*angleDirection;
      if ((angle>QUARTER_PI)||(angle<0)) {
        angle=QUARTER_PI;
      }
    }
    if (mouseButton==RIGHT) {
      angle=angle+speed*angleDirection;
      if ((angle>QUARTER_PI)||(angle<0)) {
        angleDirection=-angleDirection;
        angle=QUARTER_PI;
      }
    }
  }
```

(Edit > Auto Format (Ctrl+T / CMD + T) will make it easier to spot `{}` issues)

Have fun learning!